# Homework on binary search trouble

Tags: java

I'm Trying to put a decimal into an array and search for it using a binary search and it is not working how I want it. This is my code. I need to get the number 45.3 using this and I don't know what I'm doing wrong so please help.

```
class Project3
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double[] data= new double[6];
        data[0]=-3;
        data[1]=10;
        data[2]=5;
        data[3]=24;
        data[4]=45.3;
        data[5]=10.5;
        binarySearch(data[4]);
    }
    public boolean binarySearch(int key)
    {
        int size=6;
        int low=0;
        int high=size-1;
        while(high>=low)
        {
            int middle = (low + high) / 2;
            if(data[middle] == key)
            {
                return true;
            }
            if(data[middle] < key)
            {
                low=middle+1;
            }
            if(data[middle]>key)
            {
                high=middle-1;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: binary search works only on sorted arrays

Comment: Your passing an int into your method. Why?

Comment: Decimals In Java ? It is a reference ? This is useful your you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: read up on binary search: https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/binary-search/

Comment: Does this code even compile? How do you access `data` array from inside the method? Also, you name parameter `key`, but pass it an actual value.

Answer (score 0):

First you should read what binary search is. It works only on sorted arrays. Either insert the data in a sorted order or create a method to sort the data.

`

```
 class Project3
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double[] data= new double[6];
        data[0]=-3;
        data[1]=10;
        data[2]=5;
        data[3]=24;
        data[4]=45.3;
        data[5]=10.5;
        binarySearch(data[4]);//are you doing any thing with the result.
    }
    public boolean binarySearch(int key)// you can not pass a double value to int.
    {
        int size=6;//It's better to use data.length instead of hard coding it.
        int low=0;
        int high=size-1;
        while(high>=low)
        {
            int middle = (low + high) / 2;
            if(data[middle] == key)//from where are you passing the data array.
            {
                return true;
            }
            if(data[middle] < key)
            {
                low=middle+1;
            }
            if(data[middle]>key)
            {
                high=middle-1;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

`

the below code will work.
`

```
public class Project3 {
    static double[] data;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        data = new double[6];
        data[0] = -3;
        data[1] = 5;
        data[2] = 10;
        data[3] = 10.5;
        data[4] = 24;
        data[5] = 44.5;
        System.out.println(binarySearch(data[4]));
        System.out.println(binarySearch(90));
    }
    public static boolean binarySearch(double key) {
        int size = data.length;
        int low = 0;
        int high = size - 1;
        while (high >= low) {
            int middle = (low + high) / 2;
            if (data[middle] == key)
                return true;
            if (data[middle] < key)
                low = middle + 1;
            if (data[middle] > key)
                high = middle - 1;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score -2):

change key to double. then make the array a member variable to you can access it in the whole class.

```
static double[] data = new double[6];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    data[0] = -3;
    data[1] = 10;
    data[2] = 5;
    data[3] = 24;
    data[4] = 45.3;
    data[5] = 10.5;
    System.out.println(binarySearch(data[4]));
}

public static boolean binarySearch(double key) {
    int size = 6;
    int low = 0;
    int high = size - 1;
    while (high >= low) {
        int middle = (low + high) / 2;
        if (data[middle] == key) {
            return true;
        }
        if (data[middle] < key) {
            low = middle + 1;
        }
        if (data[middle] > key) {
            high = middle - 1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

this code is working for me and gets the right answer

Comment: Should sort first, do you want him to get an F? '==' on doubles is not an A either.

Comment: It works only because 5 < 45.3 and 24 < 45.3. Array must be sorted before to use that algorithm.